# Displaying a sixel image in a terminal without a line break afterwards

Tags: terminal

I would like to display an image in a terminal inline, without a line break afterwards. I came across the [Sixel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixel) format, but all examples I've found move the cursor to the next line after the image is displayed.

```
% cat hi.sixel; echo rest
(sixel image here)
rest
%
```

Using the script from [Sixel Demo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixel#/media/File:Sixel_demo.png):

```sh
#!/bin/sh
echo
echo
echo
echo -n before
printf 'G1BxIzA7MjswOzA7MCMxOzI7MTAwOzEwMDswIzI7MjswOzEwMDswIzF+fkBAdnZAQH5+QEB+fiQjMj8/fX1HR319Pz99fT8/LSMxITE0QBtcCg==' | base64 -d
echo -n after
echo
echo
echo
```

I get the following output (note an *extra* blank line between sixel and "after"):

[image: "before" printed on the same line as the sixel, but "after" is on the line after next]

- Is this behavior specified by the Sixel standard?
- How can I display a sixel image inline, like this?

```
% cat hi.sixel; echo rest
(sixel image here)rest
%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible (assuming the terminal supports it) by first emitting the `ESC [?8452h` control sequence.

```bash
echo -ne "\033[?8452h" && cat image.sixel && echo "<-- Bottom-Right"
```

See:

- [Graphics position](https://github.com/mintty/mintty/wiki/CtrlSeqs#graphics-position) (`mintty`)
- [Sixel Graphics](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Sixel-Graphics:CSI-?-Pm-h:Ps-=-8-4-5-2.BAC) (`xterm`)

Comment: fwiw, [xterm](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Sixel-Graphics:CSI-?-Pm-h:Ps-=-8-4-5-2.BAC) credits `8452` to a program named Rlogin.  It's not an "ANSI sequence", per se.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Thanks for the additional link and documentation about this sequence. I also rephrased my answer (s/ANSI sequence/control sequence).

Answer (score 0):

I never found an answer for Sixel, but Kitty's [Terminal graphics protocol](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/graphics-protocol/) has options to control image placement, including inline via `c`, `r` and `C` options.

Example displaying a PNG file inline taking 10 columns and 1 row:

```bash
printf "\e_Gf=100,t=f,c=10,r=1;$(echo -n hi.png | base64)\e\\"
```

Answer (score 0):

@Koterpillar The utility *base64* is causing the newline - not Sixel. Recommend using the Sixel format

```
DCS Pa ; Pb ; Ph q  Ps..Ps ST
```

referenced in *ctlseqs.txt* if xterm installed (usually at /usr/share/doc/xterm) or
https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html. See topic **Graphics**, subtopic **Sixel Graphics**.

Here is the Sixel file (name it hi.sixel) from the link, with an excellent explanation, you provided. The two <ESC> characters are entered by CTL+v esc in vim or CTL+q esc in emacs. Also, see
https://www.digiater.nl/openvms/decus/vax90b1/krypton-nasa/all-about-sixels.text for more info.

```
 <ESC>Pq
 #0;2;0;0;0#1;2;100;100;0#2;2;0;100;0
 #1~~@@vv@@~~@@~~$
 #2??}}GG}}??}}??-
 #1!14@
 <ESC>\
```

To print inline (without line break) use ESC/CTL sequences,

```
echo -n 'before'; cat hi.sixel; echo -en "\e[A\e[9Gafter" # Cursor up one line; move to column 9
```

See CSI Ps A and CSI Ps G in the reference.

In a bash script, the above is

```
echo -n 'before'
echo -en $'\ePq
#0;2;0;0;0#1;2;100;100;0#2;2;0;100;0
#1~~@@vv@@~~@@~~$
#2??}}GG}}??}}??-
#1!14@
\e\\'
echo -e "\e[9Gafter" # Move cursor to column 9
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining and/or showing what it does?

Comment: @Koterpillar Sorry for the delay: internet outage. You were not specific in your comment. Did you want an explanation for the cursor movements or the Sixel sequence? I did a complete rewrite providing links for both and how to inline output. Hope it helps.

Comment: From what I understand, the "no newline" is implemented manually using `echo -e "\e[A\e[9G"`. This moves the cursor back _in this case_ but I don't know the current cursor position before displaying the image, so unfortunately this isn't useful to me.